# find files without extension

Tags: bash, shell, find, wildcards

Let say I have:

```
foo.txt
bar
baz.ooo
```

If I use `ls -1 !(*.*)` then I'll get only `bar` on the output. Great, now I wish to have same results with find - some `find -regex` that will do the job.

**NOTE:**

`find -name !(*.*)` is not the answer as `!(*.*)` in it is still Bash's glob which I can NOT use.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

you could use: `find . -type f ! -name "*.*"`
the `!` negates the following expression, here a filename that contains a '.'

you can also use the `-maxdepth` option to reduce the search depth.

Comment: I like your answer the most as mine has some other constrains for the filenames and yours is bullet proof.

Comment: This is also great when `ls -1 !(*.*)` won't work because the `!` gives "Event not found."

Comment: @Noumenon do `set +H` to solve that

Comment: If you treat `.gitignore` as a file without extension (like Node's path.extname()), use `! -name "?*.*"` instead of `! -name "*.*"`